# Implementing OAuth2 Implicit Grant with Spring Security

Tags: spring-security, oauth-2.0, microservices, spring-security-oauth2

I am building a new application using microservices with a frontend UI using React JS. I have created an auth microservice using Spring Boot and OAuth 2.0. For single page applications I have read that I should use the implicit grant instead of the password grant. The auth microservice will support this but my question is where would I implement the UI for the user to put their username and password? Would it be within the auth microservice or would I have to create a separate UI application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The authentication form will be on your auth microservice. Think for example as you use google login. You'll see google login page even if you have your own microservice. It's because authentication provider is google and you redirect user to login to google.

I implemented all grant types a while back. May be [this](https://github.com/anealkeshi/springboot-microservices) will help you.

Comment: Great, I will take a look. I was unsure if that a microservice should offer an API and a UI. Where should user registration be placed, also in the auth microservice as well?

Comment: one of the misconception about microservice is that it only offers APIs. Regarding user registration, it can be placed within auth microservice or you can separate it depending on your need and breakdown.